# Tesseract 4 : is there a maximum resolution that an input image can have when page segmentation is enabled?

Tags: tesseract

My Java project deals with OCRing pdfs to index them. Each pdf page is converted into a png which is then piped to tesseract 4.

The pdf->png conversion uses `renderImageWithDPI` from PDFBox PdfRenderer :

buffImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(currentPage,
                            PNG_DENSITY,
                            ImageType.GRAY);

with `PNG_DENSITY = 300` as advised on tesseract's wiki to get best results.

The OCR command is

The command used for tesseract is

```
tesseract input.png output -l fra --psm 1 --oem 1
```

I also tryed `--psm 2 or 3` which also involve page segmentation ie

> 1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
>
> 2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
>
> 3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)

With a scanned PDF (producer/creator is Adobe Acrobat 7.0, which involves copyrighted content so I can't share it) of 146 pages, tesseract makes endless computations (the process never ends) on a given page (85).

As it was too long to test (ie : wait until page 85 gets OCRed), I decided to generate an extract of this pdf with Evince "print to file" feature.

Now the pdf produced by Evince (producer/creator is cairo 1.14.8), Tesseract handles it successfully (ie the image gets OCRed).

The difference is the image resolution. The image that fails is 4991x3508 pixels whereas the one that succeeds is only 3507x2480 pixels.

*Please note : tesseract in "Sparse text with OSD" (ie --psm 12) handles the page "successfully" although the text (on 2 columns) is not understandable (ie the 2 columns are mixed)*

**EDIT after several trials and errors**
It looks like the input image has to have a width **strictly less than 4000 pixels** to work with page segmentation. Looking at Tesseract source code, in a class called "pgedit" the canvas size seems limited to 4000 x 4000 as the constructor of a "ScrollView" (for whatever it serves) is :

```
ScrollView::ScrollView(const char* name, int x_pos, int y_pos, int x_size,
                   int y_size, int x_canvas_size, int y_canvas_size, bool y_axis_reversed)
```

So my question now is, why is there a limit of 4000 pixels wide / high to use page segmentation, and what should I do if a pdf page converted to png at 300dpi exceeds 4000 pixels (either wide or high or both) ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: I removed the PDFBox label as this isn't a PDFBox question.

Comment: Consider taking this very reasonable question over to the project tracker at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tesseract-ocr